# Interpretation of random matrix eigenvectors in physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, mathematical-physics

Random matrices may be used in physics to replace Hamiltonian of complex system, for instance in nuclear physics. Eigenvalues of these matrices are simply interpreted as the energy levels (even if we're more interested in the statistical distribution of the levels with this approach) of the nuclei, but what would be a physical interpretation of the matrices eigenvectors ? I thought they could be related to the widths of the levels, but this still looks quite unclear to me for now.